# jQuery not adding class to selected div id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying this code on website but it not working at all.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
var link = jQuery(location).attr('pathname');
var fullurl = jQuery(location).attr('href');
if (link.split("/")[3] === "sardines") {
    console.log("fullurl = " + fullurl);
    console.log("pathname = " + link);
    console.log("loop sardines");
    jQuery('#sardines').addClass('capik');
    console.log("end addClass");
}
else if (link.split("/")[3] === "saba"){
    console.log("loop saba");
    jQuery('#saba').addClass('capik');
    console.log("end addClass");
}
else{
    console.log("end of loop");
}
```

```
<div id="all-product-categories">
<div class="all-categories">
    <h2>All Categories</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div id="sardines" class="sardines col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/sardines" alt="Sardines">
            <div class="box">
                <span>SARDINES</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/sardines.png" alt="sardines" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="saba" class="saba col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/saba" alt="Saba">
            <div class="box">
                <span>SABA</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/saba.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="mackerel" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/mackerel" alt="Mackerel">
            <div class="box">
                <span>MACKEREL</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/mackerel.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="tuna" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/tuna" alt="Tuna">
            <div class="box">
                <span>TUNA</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/tuna.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div id="bakedbeans" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/baked-beans" alt="Baked Beans">
            <div class="box">
                <span>BAKED BEANS</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/baked-beans.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="coconut" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/coconut" alt="Coconut">
            <div class="box">
                <span>COCONUT</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/coconut.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="fruits" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/fruits" alt="Fruits">
            <div class="box">
                <span>FRUITS</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/fruits.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="vegetables" class="col-3">
        <a href="/index.php/products/vegetables" alt="Vegetables">
            <div class="box">
                <span>VEGETABLES</span>
                <img src="images/AYAM-product-categories/vegetables.png" alt="saba" width="150" height="150" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me with this issue. The script are running fine on the site but the jQuery not adding any class on the selected id. The loop also working fine. How to make the jQuery add the new class on the selected div id. Here i'm attaching the screenshot for the console that show the script are running fine and screenshot for the html. But the class are not added into the selected one.Look like it skipping the addClass script there.

This is when i'm on sardines page.

Comment: can you add the value of `location` and `pathname`? that would make easier to spot the issue.

Comment: I just update the console @ROOT
For the development page you can view here. https://ematic-ayambrand-com-my.cloudaccess.host/index.php/products/sardines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code with `jQuery(document).ready`. Your code might have been executed before the html was fully loaded. Means that your selectors got executed when the element is not present yet..

```
// document.ready
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var link = jQuery(location).attr('pathname');
    console.log("url = " + link);
    console.log(link.split("/")[3]);
    console.log(link.split("/")[3] === "sardines");
    if (link.split("/")[3] === "sardines") {
        console.log("loop sardines");
        jQuery('#sardines').addClass('class');
        console.log("end addClass");
    }
    else if (link.split("/")[3] === "saba"){
        console.log("loop saba");
        jQuery('#saba').addClass('class');
        console.log("end addClass");
    }
    else{
        console.log("end of loop");
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- A not working example, inspect element you see there's no class -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#test").addClass("test");
</script>
<div id="test">
  Test
</div>
```

```html
<!-- A working example, inspect element you see there's a class -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").addClass("test");
  });
</script>
<div id="test">
  Test
</div>
```

Hope that helps